# How do I render an image uploaded in Craft 2 CMS?

Tags: craftcms

I am trying to render a single image I have uploaded to my Craft 2 CMS project. However, I have a broken file path so it appears it is trying to render the image but can't find it. I am working locally using http://localhost/ I have created a new assets source as shown in the supporting image.

[image]

Next I have added in the following to my _layout.html that lives within my templates folder.

```
                {% for asset in entry.introImage %}
                    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "File System Path" needs to be an [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths). So use something like `/Users/al-76/sites/craft-site/public/img` instead of just `/img`.

Also, fwiw, we've got a great SE site specifically for Craft CMS - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Jalen. I now have it working. Took me two hours. I removed the localhost from the URL* input field and then by change pressed the Tools > Update asset indexes. I now notice that for any image I uploaded via the CMS a copy of that image is created in my /img folder. It was a challendge but even on my first day with Craft it seems to be the kind of CMS I am looking for. Big thank you for your help.

Comment: I've been using it for awhile and I feel pretty similarly about it :P It's definitely well thought-out and a joy to use.